# A is B times X? How do I solve for this.

Tags: linear-algebra

This has to be stupidly simple and easy, but I can't think of it. I havent done much math in a long time.

0.8 times X = 48. X = 60. But I figured that out by multiplying 60 by 0.8. If I don't know it's 60, how do I solve for X? From my elementary days I remember you can flip components across the = sign, so `0.8X = 48` and `48/X = 0.8` but that just moves the problem around.

Comment: Why not do $\frac{48}{0.8} = \frac{480}{8}= 60$ ?

Comment: @WaveX Because that's literally magic and you people are wizards. Ty.

Comment: To avoid headaches and brain strain you can to $0.8x = 48\implies 8x = 480\implies x = \frac {480}8 = 60$.  Even *less* strain.  $0.8x = 48\implies 8x = 480\implies 4x = 240\implies 2x = 120 \implies x = 60$.  It's *not* magic.  It's ... comfort.

Comment: Or see that $0.8$ and $48$ have $8$s in them... so $0.8 X = 48$ so $.1X = 6$ and just multiply both sides by $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way for us old geezers who don't like decimals: since $0.8 = \frac {4}{5}$...

$$0.8 x = 48 \Rightarrow \dfrac {4x}{5} = 48 \Rightarrow 4x = 240 \Rightarrow x = 60$$